# Splitting json elements in an array using json_array in mySQL

Tags: mysql, json, database, mariadb

I am trying to retrieve some information from a mySQL database table where i am creating a column of json type. Here i am entering a full json array that consists of individual jsons.

```
{"Date": "2019-09-30", "TableName": "es_apn_1", "Count": "3"}, {"Date": "2019-09-30", "TableName": "es_response_1", "Count": "297"}, {"Date": "2019-09-30", "TableName": "es_group_1", "Count": "356"}
```

So i am trying to get individual jsons using json_array() and json_object() and then get their respective values.

I have tried entering the json in simply like :

```
{"Date": "2019-09-30", "TableName": "es_apn_1", "Count": "3"}, {"Date": "2019-09-30", "TableName": "es_response_1", "Count": "297"}, {"Date": "2019-09-30", "TableName": "es_group_1", "Count": "356"}
```

or in an array form like:

```
[{"Date": "2019-09-30", "TableName": "es_apn_1", "Count": "3"}, {"Date": "2019-09-30", "TableName": "es_response_1", "Count": "297"}, {"Date": "2019-09-30", "TableName": "es_group_1", "Count": "356"}]
```

or in a json:

```
{{"Date": "2019-09-30", "TableName": "es_apn_1", "Count": "3"}, {"Date": "2019-09-30", "TableName": "es_response_1", "Count": "297"}, {"Date": "2019-09-30", "TableName": "es_group_1", "Count": "356"}}
```

The query that i used to fetch my result is:

```
select json_object(js,'Date'), json_object(js,'TableName'), json_object(js,'Count') from (select json_array(jsondata) as js);
```

where jsondata is the name of column where the above entries are present.

But i get the result eveytime in this format.

```
{"[\"{\\\"Date\\\": \\\"2019-09-30\\\", \\\"TableName\\\": \\\"es_apn_1\\\", \\\"Count\\\": \\\"3\\\"}, {\\\"Date\\\": \\\"2019-09-30\\\", \\\"TableName\\\": \\\"es_response_1\\\", \\\"Count\\\": \\\"297\\\"}, {\\\"Date\\\": \\\"2019-09-30\\\", \\\"TableName\\\": \\\"es_group_1\\\", \\\"Count\\\": \\\"356\\\"}\"]": "Date"} | {"[\"{\\\"Date\\\": \\\"2019-09-30\\\", \\\"TableName\\\": \\\"es_apn_1\\\", \\\"Count\\\": \\\"3\\\"}, {\\\"Date\\\": \\\"2019-09-30\\\", \\\"TableName\\\": \\\"es_response_1\\\", \\\"Count\\\": \\\"297\\\"}, {\\\"Date\\\": \\\"2019-09-30\\\", \\\"TableName\\\": \\\"es_group_1\\\", \\\"Count\\\": \\\"356\\\"}\"]": "TableName"} | {"[\"{\\\"Date\\\": \\\"2019-09-30\\\", \\\"TableName\\\": \\\"es_apn_1\\\", \\\"Count\\\": \\\"3\\\"}, {\\\"Date\\\": \\\"2019-09-30\\\", \\\"TableName\\\": \\\"es_response_1\\\", \\\"Count\\\": \\\"297\\\"}, {\\\"Date\\\": \\\"2019-09-30\\\", \\\"TableName\\\": \\\"es_group_1\\\", \\\"Count\\\": \\\"356\\\"}\"]": "Count"}
```

Can you help me with the query or the format in which i should insert my entries to correctly get desired output?

Comment: *"or in a json:"* that format which you call json -> `{{"Date": "2019-09-30", "TableName": "es_apn_1", "Count": "3"}, {"Date": "2019-09-30", "TableName": "es_response_1", "Count": "297"}, {"Date": "2019-09-30", "TableName": "es_group_1", "Count": "356"}}` isn't json ...  Check it on https://jsonlint.com/

Comment: .. also why not storing it in a SQL table instead? From the looks of it that data seams pretty rational to me

Comment: @RaymondNijland actually this was just a snippet of my entry. I will be entering multiple entries with multiple key value pair which may differ and add another column to differentiate between them. So thats why i was checking if i could achieve it.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with this command:

```
CREATE TABLE tbl (id int auto_increment primary key, jdat json);

INSERT INTO tbl (jdat) 
  VALUES ('[{"Date": "2019-09-30", "TableName": "es_apn_1", "Count": "3"},
            {"Date": "2019-09-30", "TableName": "es_response_1", "Count": "297"},
            {"Date": "2019-09-30", "TableName": "es_group_1", "Count": "356"}]');

select JSON_EXTRACT(jdat,'$[0].Date') from tbl
```

See my little demo here: https://rextester.com/DPQ80237

As @Raymond Nijland remarked quite correctly, the recommended way of storing such information would be in a proper table, like show here:

```
create table tbl2 (id int auto_increment primary key, refid int, tdate date, tname nvarchar(32), tcount int);

INSERT INTO tbl2 (refid, tdate, tname, tcount) 
  VALUES (1,'2019-09-30','es_apn_1',3),
         (1,'2019-09-30','es_response_1',297),
         (1,'2019-09-30','es_group_1',356);
```

With such a design the data contained is much more easily accessible for searches or `JOIN`s with other tables ...

Comment: From the looks of it that data seams pretty rational to me storing it in a SQL table seams more logical to me ...

Comment: Yes, @RaymondNijland, I would *almost always* favour the storage in a "real" table format! The only exception I can see where the JSON data would be helpful is that where the data is of interest to the limited context of a single element (record). And where nobody would ever bee searching for any of its attributes!
I only posted this answer to show, that there *is a way* of doing what OP wanted. I do not necessarily agree with OP's approach.

Comment: *" And where nobody would ever bee searching for any of its attributes! "* well you could index JSON aswell, with generated columns..Or use a TEXT copy which you can FULLTEXT index.. Or make a inverted index table ..All options work if you really have to annyhow we are moving a bit to much offtopic as i already asked the topicstarter why was choosen for json storage..

Comment: Thank you everyone for your response, i forgot to mention on my question that i have already tried that and achieved correct result from this type of data entry. But i have to try another approach where i could just enter a single json for a single date entry where i could be able to fetch all my results with just one query.